# kendo ui mvc grid custom cells based on data cell values

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

i need to change style of grid cell based data value

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Width(60).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
```

this column takes only two values "Open,Closed" i need to Add class="label label-success" When the value = Closed And class="label label-danger" When the value = Open

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
columns.Bound(c =>c.Status).Title("Status").ClientTemplate("#if(Status=='Open') {#" +
                      "<label class='label label-success'>#=Status#</label>" +
                      "# } else {# " +
                        "<label class='label label-danger'>#=Status#</label>" +
                       "# } #").Width(60).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
```

Let me know if any concern.